# Jquery UI Scroll Bar not fitting the contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI Scroll Bar http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll This is the link to my customized scroll bar http://providentfeed.com/beta/search.php. You can see at the bottom where I am using it for pagination. The problem is that scroll bar is starting from middle and don't move on to the start and when we move to right it shows a empty space after that means I am not able to move it up to corners. In Jquery default demo, it is perfect. Any idea please, to fix this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am inspect your page and think your problem is for `CSS`. `div` of class `.scroll-bar` and its child `div` which class is `.ui-handle-helper-parent` are not equal. If this two `div` have same width then it will work as you required. In this page the computed width of class `.scroll-bar` is `289px`. You would try

```
$('.ui-handle-helper-parent').width('289px');
```

or

```
$('.ui-handle-helper-parent').width($('.scroll-bar').width());
```

If you have any `border` in `.scroll-bar` then actual width of this `div` is including right and left border.

Comment: Thank you Alam, you are right about the sizes of both divs should be same, when I do it from firebug it works but when I add the code, it is overwritten by script and it changes the width to nearly 79px something.